# VIM+Ctags doesn't work in WinXP

Tags: windows, vim, ctags, omnicppcomplete

Okay guys, you're my only help :)

I have GVim v. 7.3, Exuberant CTags 5.8, omnicppcomplete (0.41) - all latest, to be exact.
I'm trying to generate tags to use in VIM, but it seems to totally ignore data in tags file.

I've used `ctags` to generate `tags` file for bada framework - the file seems to be okay, class definitions present etc. I also tried to apply the same command to STL from Visual Studio.

```
ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q --language -force=C++ "c:\bada\1.0.0\Include\"
```

Also, I've mapped generating tags via hotkey.

```
map <C-F12> :!ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q .
```

Trying to use any of files generated by these commands did not succeed.
The command `:tags` shows empty tag list, but doesn't give any error, and I have no clue how to fix this.

Comment: What is the output of `:set tags?`.  `:tags` only shows the current tag stack, so unless you've pressed (e.g.) `Ctrl-]`, it won't show anything.

Comment: Yes, AI, you're right. I thought it was a problem with tags file being read by VIM - however it was just it didn't accept path with spaces.
And thanks for help )

Answer (score 3):

Yes, seems that vim actually handles spaces in a weird way (Windows only?), however there are workarounds: either use dos 8.3 short names or use a wildcard instead of a space (?), like

```
set tags=c:\program?files?(x86)\vim\tags
```

PS: which tag files was successfully loaded could be checked with the

```
:echo tagfiles()
```

command

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with path to tags file: c:\Program Files\Vim\bada. The VIM didn't want to parse string with spaces no matter what the slashes/backslashes used.

Reinstalling VIM to c:\VIM solved the problem.

Comment: I would suggest that your tags file should be local to your project dir.  Putting user data into Program Files is pretty much considered an error anymore, and on Vista and Win7 you can't even do it without explicitly elevating privileges.